# How do you get a DbEntityEntry EntityKey object with unknown name

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

Shouldn't I be able to get the EntityKey object using the complex property method or property method for the DbEntityEntry. I couldn't find any examples [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679271%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), but I presume that this is possible in Entity Framework 5. I Will not know the name of the entity key or entity as I am using a generic repository interface.

Comment: Can you share your code? Can you share the exact error/exception that you are getting? Please don't include [tags in your title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/189763). Is this specific to Entity Framework 5?

Comment: Yes it is specific to Entity Framework 5 , thats why I specified it in the title and my actual question.

Comment: No code because it is just a theoretical question. I have found other ways to get the primary key value of an entity, but I was curious if you could get at it from this path

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you have a `DbEntityEntry` object you get the `EntityKey` by first finding the wrapped `ObjectContext`:

```
var oc = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
```

Then you can find the entity key by

```
oc.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(dbEntityEntryObject.Entity)
    .EntityKey
```

**EDIT**

I created two extension methods that get you close to what you want:

```
public static EntityKey GetEntityKey<T>(this DbContext context, T entity)
    where T : class
{
    var oc = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
    ObjectStateEntry ose;
    if (null != entity && oc.ObjectStateManager
                            .TryGetObjectStateEntry(entity, out ose))
    {
        return ose.EntityKey;
    }
    return null;
}

public static EntityKey GetEntityKey<T>( this DbContext context
                                       , DbEntityEntry<T> dbEntityEntry)
    where T : class
{
    if (dbEntityEntry != null)
    {
        return GetEntityKey(context, dbEntityEntry.Entity);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now you can do

```
var entityKey = dbContext.GetEntityKey(entity);
```

or

```
var entityKey = dbContext.GetEntityKey(dbEntityEntryObject);
```

The runtime will pick the right overload.

Note that the syntax that you proposed (`dbEntityEntryObject.Property<EntityKey>()`) can't work when the entity has a composite key. You have to get the `EntityKey` from the entity itself.

Comment: I have seen this snippet of code in some other stackoverflow answers I just thought that maybe with EF 5.0 you could maybe do something like dbEntityEntryObject.Property<EntityKey>(); It seems to me that it would have been nice to expose the EntityKey as a property

Comment: I even think it should not be hard to introduce a property `dbEntityEntryObject.EntityKey`. You could submit a change request, or check if it's already there: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic.

Comment: Thanks, those extension methods will come in handy. I suppose in the end your solution is probably how the ef code base would be changed anyway.

Comment: Doesn't work at all for me, EF6, model first, T4 templates, this always returns null for objects that are newly created ... solutions?

Comment: @Mvision Only *attached* entities have entity keys.

Comment: @Shimmy Try this:

`var objSet = oc.CreateObjectSet<T>();`
`var entityKey = oc.CreateEntityKey(objSet.EntitySet.Name, entity);`