# Setting EntityKey in EF6 DbContext

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have upgraded my project from EF5 to 6 - I also decided to use the new code generation strategy.

This means a bit of pain for me - I need to go through all my DALs and switch them from ObjectContext to  DbContext.

After making the following code change, I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'EntityKey':

```
using (var ctx = DbContextManager<MyDataContext>.GetManager("MyDataContext"))
{
   var label = new Label()
   {
      Id = item.Id,
      EntityKey = new EntityKey("MyDataContext.Labels", "Id", item.Id)
   };

   ctx.DbContext.Labels.Attach(label);
   this.WriteNonKeyData(label, item);
   ctx.DbContext.SaveChanges();
   return ReadData(label);
}
```

Is there another accessor for EntityKey in DbContextManager, or another strategy that's recommended for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You could always use this approach:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15896086/61164

However, it's still based on ObjectContext, as EntityKeys are not used in DbContext.  I'd suggest rewriting your code to not use them, especially since ObjectContext is essentially going away in EF7.

Comment: "I'd suggest rewriting your code to not use them". I'd like to do that but I don't understand why DbContext doesn't use them. What is the equivalent, if any? I'm a bit new to EF so sorry if this is obvious.